# Selecting a sheet and getting a run time errror with a collection reference

Tags: vba, excel

I have a collection whose first index contains the string `Automatic`.

There is a `sheet` in my workbook titled `Automatic`. I am trying to select the sheet with: `sheets(myCollection(1)).select` and I'm receiving the error:`Run-Time Error '13': Type Mismatch`.

I also tried: `sheets(" & myCollection(1) & ")` but this errored out as well.

I checked the `VarType` of `myCollection(1)` and it returned `8` which is a `string`. Any thoughts why this select doesn't work?

**Update:** I used the following workaround, but still really confused why this didn't work in the first place: `myString = myColleciton(1)` and then `sheets(myString).select`.

Comment: Try printing out the TypeName(mycollection(1)), it might help you understand what's happening. Also make sure the sheet exists when you try and select it. Your code should work.

Comment: We would need to see the code that's adding the items to `myCollection` to be able to explain what's happening when you retrieve an item.

Comment: are you sure this worked? myString = myColleciton(1) and then sheets(myString).select. there's a typo there, is it Collection or Colleciton?

Comment: Try sheets(myCollection(1).Value)  if this works then you are referencing an object in you collection.  If you only want the Objects value to be stored in the collection then use:  myCollection. key, Object.Value when adding the object to your collection.